# Pre-compact definition

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

X is compact set iff X closed and pre-compact.
X is called pre-compact if $\overline{X}$ is compact.
But in some texts, I found that X pre-compact is  totally bounded.
Is that two definitions of pre-compact have the same meaning?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is *your* definition of pre-compact? Please state it in the question.

Comment: This is not the same thing : in a complete metric space, the two meanings coincide, but in general they don't. In my opinion, one should use "relatively compact" to say that the closure is compact.

Answer (score 2):

In a metric space $X$ compact implies $X$ closed. As then $X=\overline{X}$, $X$ is also precompact.

If $X$ is assumed to be precompact, so $\overline{X}$ is compact, and $X$ is closed too so that $X=\overline{X}$, $X$ is compact.

So the statement is trivial in any metric space.

$X$ precompact is equivalent to totally bounded in a *complete* metric space.

It's better to know the general metric fact $X$ is compact iff $X$ is complete and totally bounded.